# Scala - Map join values to keys?

Tags: scala

I have the following map with target node "E":

```
val map = Map("A" -> "B", "A" -> "C", "C" -> "D", "C" -> "E")
```

It describe a directed node graph, which looks like:

```
  
  A
 / \
 B  C
   / \     
  D   E
```

I need to enter the graph at any point and generate a route to the target node.

```
Example 1: Enter at A -> Route: A->C->E
Example 2: Enter at D -> Route: D->C->E
Example 3: Enter at B -> Route: B->A->C->E
```

Does anyone know of a compact algo which could do this as this must have been attempted before.

Look forward to hearing from you.

Cheers,

Jez

Comment: Hint: it is known as the shortest path problem...

Comment: You cannot represent this as a `Map`, since in a regular map, a key like A can only have one mapped value.

Comment: In your example there is only one path from each entry point to the target node, however generally in a graph this may not be the case.  Is this property something you can guarantee, or if not do you care which route you get?  Are you after the shortest?

Comment: As long as it is a tree (a special case of a graph) a map can be used to represent it. In this case the child has to be the key and the parent has to be the value. That makes it cheap to find the parent of a child, but it is expensive to find all children of a parent. As far as I remember the Dijstra algorithm is the fastest. Maybe that depends on the parameters and implementation.

Comment: as Jean-Philippe Pellet said, you cannot use a `Map` like that. i think you meant `Map[String,Set[String]]` instead of `Map[String,String]`, where's the key is the node, and the value is a set that contains all the node's neighbours.

Answer (score 2):

So, here is it:

```
  val map = List("A" -> "B", "A" -> "C", "C" -> "D", "C" -> "E")

  def pathOf(tree: Iterable[(String,String)],from: String,to: String, path: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = {
    if(from == to) return to::path
    tree.filterNot{ case(a,b) => path.contains(a)||path.contains(b) }
    .collect{
      case (a,b) if a == to => b
      case (a,b) if b == to => a
    }.map{ x => pathOf(tree,from,x,to::path) }
    .find{ _.nonEmpty }
    .getOrElse(Nil)
  }
```

Use case:

```
scala>  pathOf(map,"B","E").mkString("->")
res1: String = B->A->C->E

scala>  pathOf(map,"C","E").mkString("->")
res2: String = C->E
```

Answer (score 1):

As relatively new to Scala, I take this problem as a good exercise for myself and would like to share my solution with all of you. Any comments are welcomed!

BTW, the solution given by @Eastsun is a depth-first search which "memorizes" visited nodes in each path, while mine is a breadth-first search where memorization is not required (though you can definitely add this feature to improve efficiency). For trees they yield the same answer but for general graphs they can differ.

The neighbors of each node can also be cached for optimization.

```
val graph = Vector(("A","B"), ("A","C"), ("C","D"), ("C","E"))
def adjacent(a: String) = {
  graph flatMap {
    case (`a`, x) => Some(x)
    case (x, `a`) => Some(x)
    case _ => None
  }
}
def go(from: String, to: String) {
  def expand(paths: Vector[Vector[String]]) {
    paths.find(_.last==to) match {
      case Some(x) => println(x); return
      case None => expand(paths flatMap { e => 
        adjacent(e.last) map (e :+ _) 
      })
    }
  }
  expand(Vector(Vector(from)))
}
// tests
go("A","E")  // Vector(A, C, E)
go("B","E")  // Vector(B, A, C, E)
go("D","E")  // Vector(D, C, E)
```

Version with memorization: change

```
adjacent(e.last) map (e :+ _)
```

to

```
adjacent(e.last) filterNot (x => paths.flatten contains x) map (e :+ _)
```

or put this functionality in the adjacent function.